# Declaring a variable inside a module

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to declare a variable inside a module, that variable is being defined outside of the typescript scope (it's done in the html) but the compiler doesn't like it.

```
module mymodule {
    declare var myvar: any;

    module innermodule {
        function dosomething() {
            console.log(mymodule.myvar);
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler says that "Property 'myvar' does not exist on type 'typeof mymodule'".

If I change it from `declare` to `export` then it works, but I'd prefer to avoid doing that as it's not the same and might cause the script to override the value injected in the html.

I've created a [Playground code which demonstrate the problem](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=module%20moduleA%20%7B%0D%0A%09declare%20var%20varA%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09export%20var%20varB%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09module%20moduleB%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09function%20functionA()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09console.log(moduleA.varA)%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09function%20functionB()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09console.log(moduleA.varB)%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%20).

Any ideas on how to go around this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'export' and 'declare' can be used together.

```
module mymodule {
    export declare var myvar: any;

    module innermodule {
        function dosomething() {
            console.log(mymodule.myvar);
        }
    }
}
```